# Get the image src and <a> href data from posts

Tags: loop

All posts on my site contain an image wrapped in an A element and thats it. i need to store the src of the image and the href of the A element for each post from within the loop. Hope someone can help!

```
<div id='hitstatAdminMain'>
        <?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query->have_posts()) {
           while ($query->have_posts()){
              $query->the_post();

              //get and store src and href here
           }
        }
        wp_reset_query();

        ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` to perform a regular expression match on the content of the post.

```
<div id='hitstatAdminMain'>
        <?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query->have_posts()) {
           while ($query->have_posts()){
              $query->the_post();
              // Store the current iterated posts content in a variable
              $content = get_the_content();
              // Perform a global regular expression match for content of `href` attribute
              preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $content, $hrefResult);
              // Perform a global regular expression match for content of `src` attribute
              preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src=([\'"])(?<src>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $content, $srcResult);
              // preg_match_all returns an array so if you only have 1 image and 1 link you can get the first array index using `[0]`.
              $href = $hrefResult['href'][0];
              $src = $srcResult['src'][0];
           }
        }
        wp_reset_query();

        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ha! awesome. I have been searching for hours trying to find a function like this, cheers! I thought i was going to have to store all the content and loop through each character and save the needed data. This is far more efficient! Id like to be able to understand some of the code more e.g " [^>] ([\'"]) " is there any documentation you would recommend?

Comment: @TomPo101 It is called a regex expression. So if you search for regex expression tutorials/ documentation you should be able to get a basic idea.